# "the rolls come in an assortment of sizes" what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

It sound like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/3zXqpvIjeN0?t=319)

> the kit is a variety of
>   materials you would use to insulate
>   between three to five windows. just like
>   the adhesive tape and caulking, these are
>   also simple to install and the rolls
>   come in an assortment of sizes.

the kit mentioned above refers to this kind of things

[image]

I cannot understand the last part "the rolls
come in an assortment of sizes".

I guess the rolls mean some kind of tapes

[image]

assortment means "a miscellaneous collection of things"

does that part mean that the kit contains a miscellaneous collection of things that suitable to a variety of dimensions?

Comment: No, it means the tape comes in different sizes, likely different widths.

Comment: "an assortment of sizes" means "different sizes".

Answer (score 1):

An assortment is [a group of different types of something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assortment). The 'group' is rolls of tape; the different 'types' are sizes. The rolls of tape are available in different sizes.